# how to make a second level include of objects

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, windows-runtime

I have structure like this

```
class Lesson {
    List<Sign> signs { get; set; }
}

class Sign {
    List<Media> media { get; set;}
}

class Media {

}
```

Now I'm using this LINQ to get all lessons

```
var items = (from lesson in this.db.Lesson.Include("Sign")
                     where lesson.module_id == param
                     select lesson);
```

It works fine but signs list has ampty media list. I mean that attribute `media` in each object `Sign` equals null. What do I need to do to include media objects for each Sign ? Whole data is kept in database

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'd use `db.Lesson.Include("signs.media")`.

The argument to [`ObjectQuery<T>.Include`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738708.aspx) is a property *path*, not just a single root property. Note that with "signs.media" you wouldn't need to also include "signs" separately:

> Paths are all-inclusive. For example, if an include call indicates Include("Orders.OrderLines"), not only will OrderLines be included, but also Orders.

(You should adjust your property names to conform to .NET framework conventions, by the way, so you'd end up with "Signs.Media".)

Comment: @fixus Just a note, when you do multiple includes like this you may want to consider using select and projecting to an explicit object with just the fields you need. tl;dr; The sql generated gets ugly and slow :)

Comment: I thought so. Unfortunatly in this case I need every field. Do you think that even in this case I should write my own sql query ?

Comment: @Fixus: No, you should not write your own SQL. "Slow" is relative. You should think about alternatives only when the straightforward way (and that is `Include`) turns out to be too slow for its purpose in your app. *All* LINQ-to-Entities queries are slower than the raw ADO.NET/SQL counterpart. You could just stop using EF if you want or need to optimize every single millisecond.